# How to Make Hibernate Print Out IDs in the Console?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm using Hibernate/Spring. I have Hibernate configured to output HQL into the Console; it shows things like:

```
Hibernate: update sometable set some_field=?, other_field=? where id=?
```

This is great. The only additional thing I want is to replace the question-marks with REAL IDs.

The context is that I'm trying to investigate if a cascading delete is responsible for deleting a record after the parent/owner of that record is changed (say, from P1 to P2) and then the old parent P1 is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable (log4j) logging for this packages and this level:

```
org.hibernate.sql=TRACE
org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

It should produce trace messages about each parameter.

@see [thierd replaiy](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html#92035542) for an example

**added**

*Only a hint: because it would be useless if the statements and parameters are shown/logged to different places:*

> Instead of using "hibernate.show_sql" you can enable DEBUG logging for "org.hibernate.SQL". Now you should see the SQL logged in your Log4J output rather than in the console.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are these additional properties to put in hibernateProperties, or are you talking about log4j logging?

Comment: @ashes999: I am talking about Log4j.

Comment: I don't like how log4j logs to files. Hibernate is smart enough to show HQL in the console; I just want to elaborate on that. If that's not possible, log4j is a distant second solution -- if I'm using log4j, I might as well inject my own logging statements and not rely on HQL.

Comment: @ashes999: I know, it is ugly and it makes your application slow (when you have many queries), but this is the only way I know.

Comment: @ashes999: If you use log4j for this, you are not fixed to files, log4j can log to the console as well as to many other places.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but as close as I will get, I suspect